# fixed padding of 3px inside container that has percent width

Tags: css, forms

I am looking for a solution to add 3px padding (always must be 3px) inside a container that has not a standard width but percent.

Here is the problem. I have a form framework that has a label of 20% and form element of 80%

Inside the container that holds the form element (80%) a want to have a 3px padding to wrap the form element with a background. This mean that the form element will have a 3px background no more and no less.

I have tried some solutions but nothing works so far because i have to create a container width 80% percent and 3px padding and inside to set the width of the form element as (80% - 3px).

Sample code

```
<div id="formRow">
   <label style="width:20%;float:left;"> Label </label>

   <div id="formElement" style="width:80%;float:left;"> 
      <input type="text" width="???????????" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@nthan ; you can use css3 property `box-sizing` like this

CSS:

```
#formElement{
 padding:3px;
 -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing:        border-box;
 width:80%;
}
```

*note:* it's not work in IE7

**EDIT:**

If you didn't want to use css3 then you can give `margin` to it's `child` div instead of giving `padding` to it's `parent` div.

```
#formElement input{
 margin:3px
}
```

may be that' work for you.`enter code here`

**EDIT 2**

check this link it's work http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Yf2zY/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am not using css3 for this project

Comment: Even so what must be the width of input? if i set it to 100% its wrong because its actually 100% minus 6px for left and right margins.Using this i have a background color of 3px and with the border of input i can create a nice gray lay out

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the `Float:left` form your `formElement` Div and adding `style="border:solid 1px #333; padding:5px;"` to the `formRow` div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="formRow" style="padding:0px 6px 0px 0px;">
   <label style="width:20%;float:left;"> Label </label>

   <div id="formElement" style="width:80%;float:left; padding:3px;margin-right:-6px"> 
      input
   </div>
</div>
```